# {"Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'main'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"} in Docker for Lambda (FAST API)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, machine-learning

I have created a Fastapi and now trying to deploy it using Docker container to AWS lambda. but there is a error:

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'main'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}
```

I have tried everything I could.
This is my main.py file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.status import HTTP_302_FOUND,HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER
import spacy
from string import punctuation
from mangum import Mangum
import uvicorn
app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def home():
    return {"answer":"Hello World"}

@app.get('/tags')
def prep_data(text):
    tag = tokens(text, nlp)
    tags = getdict(tag)
    return {
        'tags':tags
    }

handler = Mangum(app)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # handler = Mangum(app)
    uvicorn.run('main:app', host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, reload=False, root_path="/")
```

**The error is idicating towards the main.py file that there is no main.py file, As you can see the dockerfile**:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY ./app /app

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["main.handler"]
```

My directory structure is like:

```
/app
    main.py
Dockerfile
requirements.txt
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `CMD ["app/main.handler"]`?

Comment: but i am already in the ```WORKDIR /app```. will that work?

Comment: I tried it just now, it isnt working

Comment: Hey, do you get the solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I changed the docker file. It was a issue in folder structure also.

Comment: Could you please share your solution by answering your own question.

Answer (score 1):

```
-app
 - internal
   - imp.py
   - __init__.py
 - routers
   - v1.py
   - __init__.py
 - __init__.py
 - main.py
 - requirements.txt
- Dockerfile
```

### main.py

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from mangum import Mangum

from app.routers import v1

app = FastAPI()


app.include_router(v1.router)


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Fast API App"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        print("Starting Server...")
        uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=9005, reload=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

handler = Mangum(app)
```

**Docker file**

```
# Use the base image from ECR for Python 3.8
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

COPY /app/requirements.txt /var/task/

# Upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

# Install dependencies from the dependencies directory
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

COPY ./app /var/task/app

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD [ "app.main.handler" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda function doesn't respect `WORKDIR` you set in dockerfile, when looking for handler module. It keeps looking for the module under `/var/task`. Initially I had my handler module `main` in `app` directory `/var/task/app` when I got this error. To resolve this I created a new file `lambda_function.py` under `/var/task` with `handler()` function and called the `main` `handler()` function within it. Alternatively you can move your original handler module under `/var/task`. I chose not to avoid updating import paths within my application.